How to bound the VC dimension of a new hypothesis class?
I have been looking into learning theory, and there is a particular problem regarding bounding VC dimension of a function class that I find to be interesting but difficult.
Assume $F$ is a binary-valued function class, and the functions in $F$ map the input space $X$ to $\{0,1\}$.
The VC dimension of the function class $F$ is $d$.
Based on $F$, I construct a new function class $G=\{g_f:X^2\to\{0,1\}|g_f(x_1,x_2)=\min\{f(x_1),f(x_2)\},f\in F\}$.
How can I derive a tight upper bound on the VC dimension of the function class $G$?
Is it possible to show that VC(G)$\leq2\cdot d$? If not, what is the tightest bound?
I have been thinking about this problem for a long time. Using Sauer's Lemma, I can show that VC(G)$<5\cdot d$, but I didn't find that satisfactory since this is not tight. Is it possible to prove a tighter upper bound for this problem?
